# Can I have GeForce® GTX 570 Sonic Platinum with normal GTX 570 in SLI?

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, hardware-rec

The question really describes that all. Here's a detailed disambuagation of my question:

1. Can I combine a GTX 570 Sonic Platinum Edition and a 'Normal' GTX 570?
2. If yes, then does it requires special configuration?; If no, then does it requires to be the same as my existing GTX 570 Sonic Platinum Edition?
3. If yes (again) what is the equivalent card if I combine the 2? I want to know the equivalent if:

   - 1 GTX 570 Sonic Platinum + 1 GTX 570
   - 2 GTX 570 Sonic Platinum
   - 2 GTX 570

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Nvidia, there should be no issue with this configuration. This is on Nvidia's FAQ page ([NVIDIA FAQ Page](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/technology/sli/faq#c17))

**Can I mix and match graphics cards from different manufacturers?**

*Using 180 or later graphics drivers, NVIDIA graphics cards from different manufacturers can be used together in an SLI configuration. For example, a GeForce XXXGT from manufacturer ABC can be matched with a GeForce XXXGT from manufacturer XYZ.*

**Can I mix and match graphics cards if one of them is overclocked by the manufacturer?**

*Yes. A GeForce XXXX GTX that is overclocked can be mixed with a standard clocked GeForce XXXX GTX.*

As far as the performance of an SLI configuration, I've linked below two websites that have run a similar configuration and you can see relative performance there.

[Guru 3D SLI Review](http://www.guru3d.com/articles_pages/geforce_gtx_570_sli_review,1.html)

[XBit Labs SLI Review](http://www.xbitlabs.com/articles/graphics/display/geforce-gtx-570-sli.html)

In tandem with that, an GTX570 SLI configuration performs roughly on par with a GTX 780 at its very best, and has singular GTX570 numbers at its worst. Your mileage will vary.

Comment: *performs roughly on par with a GTX 780 at its very best* does that mean that it is better if I am going to buy another GTX 570 and configure it in SLI than to buy a GTX 780?

Comment: It honestly depends on your budget, your other computer specs (does your motherboard support SLI?, do you have adequate PCI-E outputs?, do you have enough power?, can your computer case take the extra thermal heat?). If the following are all "Yes" and you're limited to another 570, I'd take the leap if you find your gaming experience lacking. Otherwise, if you've got a little wiggle room take a look at a GTX 760 or a 770. Either provide a considerable increase in performance, noise, etc.. [The GTX 760 around 66% alone](http://www.anandtech.com/show/7103/nvidia-geforce-gtx-760-review/18)

Comment: and the 770 around 75%. You can then sell your card locally and recoup some of the cost.

Comment: do I need to post my complete system specs?

Comment: Lets say I have an AMD Phenom II X3 @ 3.2 Ghz, 4GB RAM, motherboard that supports SLI, and a 500watts(branded/true power) PSU.

Comment: I'd definitely avoid a GTX 570 SLI configuration with a 500W Power supply, even if it does have the proper PCI-E cables to support it. It seems your upgrade is going to be a singular card. Take a look at the 760 or 770, whichever is closer in your budget.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort. I felt enlightened. Now I'm planning to switch to Intel so I set aside the graphic card upgrade. Thanks.

Comment: There is no way that a SLI GTX570 configuration will provide GTX780 performance.  You likely mean at least 1 generation before the 780 considering thats the CURRENT generation only just released in 2013.

Comment: Like I said, at its best it will perform similarly, although this is likely not the case most of the time.